# Add icon to Chrome OAuth Identity Screen?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am building a Chrome extension (version 2) that uses the `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` API call to start the authentication process using a Chrome Account. Very easy and works ok. Here it is the screen:

[image]

But now, I am trying to pass Google's OAuth Consent Screen Verification and they complain that the above consent screen, does not show the App Icon, and I cannot find any documentation that shows how to add that.

The manifest file for the extension has the `icons` entry and they appear as expected in other parts of the browser (like as an extension button). I am guessing that something has to be added to the manifest's `oauth2` section, which now only contains the `client_id` and `scopes`.